# MySQL function/loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I have solved this in Microsoft Excel, hopefully you can help write a function or loop inside a MySQL query script.

Need to write a script that outputs cumulative phase angles. The original data has the following form:

```
IRIG_Time                   ID      Radians
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     5       -2.7096
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     10      -2.7917
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     15      -0.713
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     20      -0.5453
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     25      -1.8958
```

The following script is what I have so far. I am pulling the data and converting the "Radians" column to degrees.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1

SELECT IRIG_Time, ID, DEGREES(Radians) FROM originaltable Where ID=5 and IRIG_Time 
between '2014-05-17 05:30' and '2014-05-17 05:31' order by IRIG_Time;
```

To explain how I solved it in Excel I'll use the following logic statement:

```
variable = if(Logical_test, Value_if_true, Value_if_false)
```

To make things easier to read: degrees = "DEGREES(Radians)"

I would like to create a new column ("Rotated") and fill it with the following function:

```
Rotated = IF(degrees<0,360+degrees,degrees)
```

Then create a new column (Cumulative), loop through the data and perform the following (contains a nested if statement):

```
Cumulative = IF((degrees-degrees(n-1))>100,Cumulative(n-1)+diff-
360,IF(diff<-100,Cumulative(n-1)+diff+360,Cumulative(n-1)+diff))

Where: degrees(n-1) is previous degrees,
Cumulative(n-1) is previous Cumulative,
diff = degrees - degrees(n-1)
```

The table below contains two series of how Cumulative should behave:

```
IRIG_Time               ID  Radians  Degrees        Rotated     Cumulative
2014-05-15 09:05:38.500 5   0.0099   0.567228217    0.567228217 -359.4327718
2014-05-15 09:05:38.533 5   0.0022   0.126050715    0.126050715 -359.8739493
2014-05-15 09:05:38.567 5   -0.0049  -0.28074932    359.7192507 -360.2807493
2014-05-15 09:05:38.600 5   -0.0126  -0.721926822   359.2780732 -360.7219268

2014-05-15 09:30:10.867 5   3.1352   179.6337279    179.6337279 -1620.366272
2014-05-15 09:30:10.900 5   3.1401   179.9144772    179.9144772 -1620.085523
2014-05-15 09:30:10.933 5   -3.1384  -179.8170744   180.1829256 -1619.817074
2014-05-15 09:30:10.967 5   -3.1337  -179.5477843   180.4522157 -1619.547784
```

Sorry...this is probably confusing. I merged the three created columns with the format of the original data. Ideally the script would return: IRIG_Time, ID, Cumulative

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I don't see any connection between your original data and your sample result...?

Comment: Sorry...this is probably confusing. I merged the three new columns in the sample results with the format of the original data. Ideally the script would return: IRIG_Time, ID, Cumulative

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the algorithm down I guess it is the stored function/procedure you need help with. This is the standard way of looping through the result of a select statement (and exiting when you are done).

Set up a CONTINUE HANDLER to know when to exit from the loop and define a CUSRSOR for reading the data. Use FETCH to read from the cursor and check if you are done by taking a look at the variable the CONTINUE HANDLER manipulates.

Hope this helps out.

```
DECLARE done          INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE               CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
DECLARE cursLine      CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM tmpTblLines ORDER BY ID;
DECLARE prodLineID    INT(11);

lineLoop:
LOOP
    FETCH cursLine INTO prodLineID;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE lineLoop;
    END IF;

    ...

END LOOP;
CLOSE cursLine;
```